# How to establish connection between WSO2 ESB to MS Dynamic 365?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to use WSO2 ESB (Which is open source) to push the data into MS Dynamics Online.

WSO2 provided some docs, but not much helpful.

Anyone tried to do the same, please share the links of article, video or any form of help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 has an [ESB connector for Dynamics 365](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/4e396cb9-eb30-4cd4-9475-52ad2c214e42). Take a look at their [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Microsoft+Dynamics+365+Connector) on how to get started.